# Ternary relationship and Key constraints

Tags: erd

If I have following ERD then what would be the key of the relationship?

[MR ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qtGy.jpg)   (cannot add the image directly)

I am confused with the relationship table? I am sure we have three tables for three entities and what about the relationship? Do I need a table? As in M:1, we don't need a table for a relationship. I can merge relationship with the entity at M side.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does the arrow in your diagram represent?

Comment: arrow mean a key constarint

Comment: That doesn't help me to understand your notation. Foreign key constraints are a physical mechanism to enforce logical domains. However, the logical domains aren't ambiguous in the diagram. The arrow isn't standard notation in Chen diagrams. Does it represent a functional dependency of C on (A, B) such that the cardinality of the relation (A,B,C) is M:N:1?